# How do I get Rust to enforce a lifetime for a *mut in unsafe code?

Tags: rust, lifetime, unsafe

I would like to call the C function `libusb1_sys::libusb_set_pollfd_notifiers()` from Rust, providing callbacks and context. The C function is:

```c
void libusb_set_pollfd_notifiers(
    libusb_context *            ctx,
    libusb_pollfd_added_cb      added_cb,
    libusb_pollfd_removed_cb    removed_cb,
    void *                      user_data 
);
```

This follows the traditional method for "closures" in C where `user_data` provides context for the callback.

The following code compiles and runs, but as far as I can tell **is wrong:**

```rust
use libusb1_sys::libusb_pollfd;
use rusb::UsbContext;

extern "system" fn usb_source_added_cb(
    _fd: libc::c_int,
    _events: libc::c_short,
    _user_data: *mut libc::c_void,
) {
    println!("USB source added");
}

extern "system" fn usb_source_removed_cb(
    _fd: libc::c_int,
    _user_data: *mut libc::c_void,
) {
    println!("USB source removed");
}

struct UsbFdChannel {
    sender:  std::sync::mpsc::Sender<libc::c_int>,
    context: rusb::Context,
}

impl UsbFdChannel {
    fn new() -> (Self, std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<libc::c_int>) {
        let context = rusb::Context::new().unwrap();
        // This gives me a `*mut libusb_context`
        let raw_context = context.as_raw();

        let (mut sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

        unsafe {
            libusb1_sys::libusb_set_pollfd_notifiers(
                raw_context,
                usb_source_added_cb,
                usb_source_removed_cb,
                &mut sender as *mut _ as *mut libc::c_void,
            );
        }

        (Self { sender, context }, receiver)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _usb_channel = UsbFdChannel::new();
}
```

I think it's wrong because once `UsbFdChannel::new()` returns, the `mut *` to `sender` is no longer valid, but `libusb`'s context is still able to use it. Am I correct?

What I would like is for this incorrect code to *not compile*. If possible, I'd like this *entire class* of incorrect code to not compile. I *think* what I want is to associate a lifetime with `sender`, or possibly with `&mut sender`, that the compiler will then enforce. Or maybe I want to "trick" rust into thinking that the lifetime of `*mut sender` is bounded by that of `&mut sender`...?

If I achieve that, then I can resolve the incorrectness however I can - by having `UsbFdChannel` take a reference, or create a reference counted/boxed/both thing, or whatever. The important thing to me (for both solving this particular problem and for learning how to write better Rust) is that I can identify and declare the ownership problem first, and then solve that problem second.

I considered using `std::marker::PhantomData`, but since `UsbFdChannel` is not parameterised by a type, I don't see how to tell it what member the `PhantomData`'s lifetime would correspond to. I also considered using some kind of non-stack allocation and reference counting, but I still want to *know* (inasmuch as Rust can tell me) that I've solved the problem. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to prevent incorrect usage of `UsbFdChannel` or of `libusb_set_pollfd_notifiers()`. The latter is currently marked as `unsafe`, which means that by definition the compiler cannot enforce its safety without additional care from the programmer. But you could still create a safe _abstraction_ around the unsafe interface, and make the unsafe interface private, so it cannot be abused. `UsbFdChannel` could be such an abstraction.

Comment: In your case, you should obtain the pointer to the sender with `Box::into_raw(Box::new(sender))`. You can then store that pointer in `Self` as you already do with `context`, and release it in `impl Drop for UsbFdChannel` using `drop(Box::from_raw(self.sender_ptr))`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Do I also need to `Pin` `sender`? If it moves I don't think that'll end well.

Comment: @user4815162342 Regarding the safe interface approach, this is more or less what I'm aiming for. I think I need to retain the pointer from `Box::into_raw()` and use a `PhantomData` marker as per the Rustonomicon. But I'm not 100% sure at this point.

Comment: You don't need to pin it if you're boxing it because a box heap-allocates the data you give it and amounts to a pointer (which `into_raw()` gives you). If you "move" a box, you're just moving the pointer, but the address it holds is unchanged. Futures need pins in the type system for efficiency, i.e. to _prevent_ boxes from cropping up everywhere (by declaring that data is held in a structure that is _already boxed_, or that it won't be broken by moves, and various other edge cases).

Comment: Good catch, you'd need a member like `PhantomData<mpsc::Sender<libc::c_int>>` - that kind of stuff is easy to forget. That's the curse and blessing of unsafe Rust - _you_ get little or no help of the compiler to prevent you from making mistakes - but if you do a good job, the _users_ of your API are safe and enjoy full safety and help from the compiler.

Comment: You might also use `File::from_raw_fd()` and send `File`s across the channel instead of `libc::c_int`s, and so on.